# How can I automatically delete a file referenced by a SQLite Database item when this item gets deleted from the database (in Android)?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

## Context

I'm creating a SQLite database to be manipulated by a Content Provider in Android.

## Question

Let's say I have the following SQLite table:

```
_id          _data
------------------------
 0       /path/to/file/0
 1       /path/to/file/1
```

Where `_id` is the primary key and `_data` is a URL to a file in the local file system.

What do I have to do in order to automatically delete a file referenced by the `_data` column when its correspondent row is deleted?

**P.S.:** I know SQLite has specific features that would accomplish this, but I'm programming for Android, which means that some of these features are not available.

## Observations

I was taking a look at the system `MediaProvider.java` class source and noticed this trigger:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS thumbnails_cleanup DELETE ON thumbnails " +
                "BEGIN " +
                    "SELECT _DELETE_FILE(old._data);" +
                "END");
```

which apparently deletes a file referenced by `thumbnails._data` when a thumbnail item is deleted.

I tried to create a similar trigger in my application, but it didn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: select... iterate deleting files... delete...

Comment: **1** - Delete from the table. **2** - Delete from the file system.

Comment: @DerGolem: safer to delete from the filesystem first, then delete from the table. if the physical file remains, then the db record should remain as well.

Comment: @MarcB Well... arguable. Shall we eat the egg first or the chicken? deleting a record is fast and possibly will be executed for sure, so the file won't be listed from the database even if the file deletion fails - due to a sharing violation (or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. But I really have to automate this. For example, if the table is referenced by an external trigger which may delete its rows, I would still have to be able to delete the referenced files.

Comment: Is it important that they be deleted immediately?  Maybe you could delete files that don't exist in the database at app startup or shutdown.

Comment: @nasch Hmm. I guess this would be enough in my case. It wouldn't be the most elegant solution, but I can use it while I'm waiting for the definitive one. Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel Huff, do you successfully delete the file? I want to have such kind of trigger to delete the disk file also in android. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @rodent_la Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution to this problem on the SQL level. What I had to do was to automate this on the app level (e.g. on a java class responsible by managing database records and files)