# What options are there for deleting a file when a SQLite row holding a reference to the file is deleted?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I currently have a `ContentProvider` that manages access to a database, which has several tables linked through foreign keys. One table maintains a list of (app-specific) audio files. There is also a table of sets; rows in the audio table must have an associated row in the set table (many-to-one).

`ON CASCADE DELETE` is active on the tables, so when rows in the set table are deleted, the rows in the audio table that referenced the set are also deleted.

My `ContentProvider` also deletes the referenced file when a call to `delete()` is made that targets the audio table.

The database side, therefore, works well. However, if the rows in the audio table are deleted, the files remain. I'd like to find a way of automatically removing those files.

One possible options seems to be to use a SQL trigger to run the undocumented `_DELETE_FILE()` function, a function apparently available in Android SQLite. Apparently the Android `MediaProvider` class uses this approach to delete files automatically.

1. Is using the `_DELETE_FILE()` function likely to work at all?
2. Would using `_DELETE_FILE()` be a violation of good practice, or indeed safe practice?
3. Is there a better, or more advisable way to achieve this automatic deletion of unreferenced files, perhaps through the `ContentProvider`? Approaches that require periodic scanning for unreferenced files strike me as inelegant, and ones that require manually performing cascades as cumbersome.

Similar question: [How can I automatically delete a file referenced by a SQLite Database item when this item gets deleted from the database (in Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241804/how-can-i-automatically-delete-a-file-referenced-by-a-sqlite-database-item-when)

Comment: You are ready to dismiss the scanning approach as not elegant but you plan to use an undocumented function? An alternative is to implement the deletion in the provider's delete method but this would be inefficient. I think you would be better with a maintenance service doing the cleanup job once in a while.

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks for the reply. _Plan to use_ is too strong a phrase; it's because I have misgivings about using an undocumented function that I've posted the question. Will think more about a periodic clean-up approach.